Whatsapp API - Delete RECEIVED message
Im working a feature using WhatsApp integration and basically the user would enter the password he would like to use.
Soon after acknowledging it, I would like to delete that message myself, instead of asking the user to delete it. Is that possible?

In WhatsApp's API or integration, there isn't a direct method to automatically delete a message that a user has sent from the user's side. WhatsApp does allow users to delete messages for everyone within a certain time frame, but this is something the user has to manually do.
